# Table overflow on the table and not body

Tags: material-ui

When table overflows it defaults to the body instead of the table. Is there to make this happen? I could make the AppBar and Tabs fixed, but its difficult to get the heights to set the padding and the scroll bar is still in the wrong place.

```
App
-Nav
--AppBar
--LeftNav
-Content
--Tests
---Tabs
----Table
```

Answer (score 1):

material ui use a div to wrap the table.
Try to use wrapperStyle to override it.Details can be found at http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table